# using an object from class A in properties of class B in matlab?

Tags: matlab, oop

I'm new to object-oriented-programming, and I want to use MATLAB OOP to write a code in MATLAB. I have a basic question: I read in MATLAB's OOP pdf (https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matlab_oop.pdf) that it's better to use a class as a structured data than a MATLAB structure. My question now is:

I have class A, and in properties of class A, i want to define two structures, named doctor_info, and patient_info. From OOP perspective should i use objects from classes doctor and patient in class A's property, or is it better to use structures and don't define class patient and doctor. If it's better to define the two classes doctor and patient, what would be the psudo-code for class A?

PS.: I searched the matlab opp, stack exchange and also the web a lot, but couldn't find my answer. In stack exchange, I found a relevant question in C++ but the answers didn't satisfy me : [How to define an object from Class A in Class B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779486/how-to-define-an-object-from-class-a-in-class-b)

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Matlab OOP perspective, the choice of `struct` or a custom class depends a lot on the particular application and considerations of maintainability, extensibility, performance, etc.

I like `structs` since I find them extremely light weight relative to custom classes and very flexible since fields can be added on-the-fly.
Some drawbacks of `structs` that come to mind when it comes to complex applications:

- Fields are added dynamically: I know I listed as a plus, but it is a plus that must be used with care.  Matlab will gladly add the misspelled field 'geuss' to a `struct` containing `guess` upon assignment, and everything will be okay until it's not.  This does not happen with custom objects since properties can only be dynamically added by inheriting from [`dynamicprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dynamicprops.html) and explicitly calling [`addprop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dynamicprops.addprop.html) (I think).
- All fields are visible and assign-able to everyone and everything.  If the application is intended for less adept users, hiding certain information or restricting/constricting assignment variables or values can be helpful or possibly needed.
- Fields within a `struct` cannot operate on the `struct`'s data after the field's creation; in my opinion, this is one of the main reasons OOP became one of the dominant programming paradigms: it can be extremely useful to have something (an object) that can store data and have it return a result without caring how it was calculated (as long as it's correct).

However, with all of the added power custom classes give, there is also overhead.  Matlab's OOP model is improving in performance, but I think `struct` still rocks on raw performance as a simple data container.
And if you don't need the power, you can avoid it without a problem.

---

One other big thing you can get with custom classes is references that can automatically update information across instances.  To illustrate this point and hopefully indirectly address your second question, consider the following `MedicalChart` class

```
classdef MedicalChart < handle

    properties
        doctor_info  = [];
        patient_info = [];
    end 

    methods
        function MC = MedicalChart(doc,pat)
            if (nargin ~= 0)
                MC.doctor_info = doc;
                MC.patient_info = pat;
            end
        end
    end

end
```

I can define the properties using two structs and create an instance of that class:

```
>> doctor.name  = 'Joe'     ;
>> doctor.phone = '555-0100';
>> patient.name = 'Bob'     ;
>> mc = MedicalChart(doctor,patient);
>> mc.doctor_info.phone
ans =
555-0100
```

But now I may have an issue.  Suppose I have a large application, and Dr. Joe has a lot of patients each with their own `MedicalChart` instance.
The `struct` `doctor` can be re-used no problem to create all of those medical charts at the cost of duplicating all the doctor's information in each instance.
It is fairly redundant in terms of memory but not a huge deal.

But what if Dr. Joe changes his number?
We would have to recreate all of the `MedicalCharts` with the updated `struct`.

We can avoid the need to recreate all of the instances and also the duplication of data by creating a Dr. Joe instance of a `Doctor` class that inherits from [`handle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html):

```
classdef Doctor < handle

    properties
        name
        phone
    end

    methods
        function doc = Doctor(name,phone)
            if (nargin ~= 0)
                doc.name  = name;
                doc.phone = phone;
            end
        end
    end

end
```

And now we create the `MedicalChart` like this:

```
>> DrJoe = Doctor('Joe','555-0100');
>> patient.name = 'Bob';
>> mc = MedicalChart(DrJoe,patient);
>> mc.doctor_info.phone
ans =
555-0100
```

Very similar.  But since I inherited from `handle`, there is only one instance of `DrJoe` in memory at one time.
So any changes made to that object are automatically accessible in `mc`:

```
>> DrJoe.phone = '555-0111';
>> mc.doctor_info.phone
ans =
555-0111
```

This is a really nice feature for doing lots of database-like things and something `structs` can't do at all.

The only complication that comes to mind is when you delete instances and what happens to their references upon deletion.
On my R2014b installation, deleting `DrJoe` works just fine since `mc` creates a local copy of `DrJoe`.
In reality, the patient should have no doctor, but accounting for that would complicate the example.

(I think in order to have everything work correctly would require `Doctor` to keep track of the `MedicalCharts` it's on and delete itself from them as part of its [destructor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-class-destructors.html).  I don't think there's a need for that here, but I thought I'd mention it.)